# Click() in jQuery is not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, bind

I have a jQuery script that I wanna use for doing certain things after clicking on

```
.header .unfocused
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="window">
<div class="header unfocused">
some more stuff
</div></div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$( ".header.unfocused" ).click(function() {
    console.log("you clicked it!");
});
```

However, after clicking on it, it doesn't do anything and I can't see anything in console. I even tried the .bind function, but it didn't work either. Please help.

Comment: bet you forgot to wrap code in `ready` handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/QhxQG/

Make sure jQuery is loading (maybe you got the URL wrong?) and that your events are created in an onready block:

```
$(function() { // a common, neater way of saying: $(document).ready(function() { 
  // events here
});
```

Comment: yes, and I want to add, be sure, that your document loaded; u can try to put your `js` code at the bottom of your page instead of puting your code in `$(function() {})`

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thank you! I'm fairly sure I tried this before, but for some reason it never worked. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $( ".header.unfocused" ).on('click', function() {
        console.log("you clicked it!");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFpUX/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Hope you have missed `$(document).ready()` handler,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $( ".header" ).click(function() {
        alert("you clicked it!");
    });
});
```